# NestJs can't resolve dependencies, why?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

New to NestJs,after the configuration according to https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database
can't figure out the problem of my code .

> > Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AdminRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument Connection at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.

Admin Module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {Admin} from "../entities/Admin";
import {TypeOrmModule} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import {AdminService} from "./admin.service";
import {AdminController} from "./admin.controller";

@Module({
    imports:[TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Admin])],
    exports: [TypeOrmModule],
    providers: [AdminService],
    controllers: [AdminController]
})
export class AdminModule {}
```

AdminController:

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller('admin')
export class AdminController {}
```

AdminService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Admin } from '../entities/Admin';


@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Admin)
        private readonly adminRepository:Repository<Admin>
    ) {}
}
```

App Module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { LoginController } from './login/login.controller';
import { RegisterController } from './register/register.controller';
import { ContactController } from './contact/contact.controller';

import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { LoginService } from './login/login.service';
import { ContactService } from './contact/contact.service';
import { RegisterService } from './register/register.service';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';

@Module({
  imports: [AdminModule],
  controllers: [AppController, LoginController, RegisterController, ContactController],
  providers: [AppService, LoginService, ContactService, RegisterService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Is the entity `Admin` decorated with `@Entity` decorator?

Comment: Yes . Otherwise would be another kind of error

Answer (score 9):

You have to import typeorm config in the app module. Refer to the below code.

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { LoginController } from './login/login.controller';
import { RegisterController } from './register/register.controller';
import { ContactController } from './contact/contact.controller';

import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { LoginService } from './login/login.service';
import { ContactService } from './contact/contact.service';
import { RegisterService } from './register/register.service';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';


@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),AdminModule],
  controllers: [AppController, LoginController, RegisterController, ContactController],
  providers: [AppService, LoginService, ContactService, RegisterService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you are missing `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()/forRootAsync()` in your `AppModule` which sets up the initial connection to the database. Make sure that is added to the `imports` array (with the necessary configurations) and you should be good to go.